# Page waiting for new POST VARIABLE

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables, post

I want to redirect my page when I get POST variable by other external domain, my page is:

http://goo.gl/kpm2GT

When you push the red button "Realizar Pago", automatically open a new windows to bank payment platform. Well, when you finish all the payment bank steps, this external web send me some POST variables with important data to my page.

This is what I want:: when someone click "Realizar Pago", the page stay waiting for new $_POST variables (from payment platform), so when the POST variables are already sended  to my page, I want redirect my page to ha payment suscessfully page.

Thanks for help guys, and sorry for my english.

Comment: @TS: i dont see the need to shorten URLs.. who knows where that could lead to.. _(you know what i mean)_

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the way you think about it.

PHP executes each request separately. When your server executes the request from the external service you could assume it doesn't know anything about that other request from your user.

The `$_POST` array is unique for every request and could not be read across requests.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, sounds like you are wanting to connect to an outside webservice from your page and then display the results to your users.  In PHP, you'd probably want to create a form processor that takes user data and then uses cURL to pass it along to the banking end.  Once the bank receives the request, they will send back a response to you which you can then display to the user or redirect them to a page that says it was a success.

cURL will wait for a while (you can specify how long it waits) for the response from the banking folks.  In this example, I have told the program to wait for 30 seconds.  If it finishes before the 30 seconds, it will go ahead and close the connection.

```
<?php

$bank_url = 'http://www.bank.com';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $bank_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

print $response;
```

Comment: The payment service like that: you post something to it and give a URL. When the payment is successful or not, it post back to the given URL. It is not a synchronous process.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: The payment service does not return immediately the needed result as a response. It makes a new post request some moments later. The PayPal IPN for example works like this.

Comment: Okay, so I think I am starting to understand that part, and for that you probably need to set up an incoming API to handle POSTs made to your script.  But where I'm confused now is how is the user involved?  Are they sitting there with the browser open just waiting for the page to refresh?

Comment: I guess this what the OP wanted to happen. I might be wrong.

Comment: Then for that, he'd need the to set up an incoming API and then have the page that the user is sitting in front of use setTimeout to initiate an AJAX call to check to see if the response from the API has made it into the DB.  If so, then refresh the page.  That's going to be a lot of work, though.  And it will require the users play along, which seems to hardly ever happen.

Comment: If he goes with this approach a far better solution is to just put a `sleep(1)` call inside a loop for like 10 steps. Perform a query to the database every step and sleep for 1 second.